# Cannot run foreach: Invalid arguments supplied

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this piece of code below to get data from two tables (items - lists all items) and categories (gets the category name and query the category table). I get invalid argument supplied.

```
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account_items 
WHERE acctname = '$acctname'")or die(mysql_error());

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($items)) {
    $itemType = $rows['item_type'];
    $itemid = $rows['id'];
    foreach ($itemType as $item) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$itemType ` 
        WHERE network_id = '$itemid' ")or die(mysql_error());
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$itemType`  is string. not array / object.

Comment: @kumar_v so how can i convert it to array?

Comment: Why do you need it to be an array? Is it a comma-separated list? Then use `explode`.

Comment: show tour data stored in `$itemType`.

Comment: Can you show us the value of ```$rows``` when you first run it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account_items WHERE acctname = '$acctname'") or die(mysql_error());

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($items)) {
    $itemType = $rows['item_type'];
    $itemid = $rows['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$item` 
        WHERE network_id = '$itemid' ")or die(mysql_error());

}
```

But you can not just echo $result as you did, becuse it is array

Comment: i was trying to echo the query to see if it will show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using the following code: remove foreach and created a nested while loop.

```
     $items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account_items WHERE acctname = '$acctname'")or die(mysql_error());
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($items)) {
    $itemType = $rows['item_type'];
    $itemid = $rows['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$itemType` WHERE network_id = '$itemid' ")or die(mysql_error());
    while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo json_encode($res);                                                                
  }                                
}
```